# Nodemon won't restart when files are updated with Express

Tags: express, nodemon

```
$nodemon -e 'js jsx' ./bin/www
```

It runs but won't restart when a 'js' or 'jsx' file is updated. I've tried a few variations;

```
$nodemon -e 'js jsx' --watch .. ./bin/www
$nodemon -e 'js jsx' --watch ./ ./bin/www
$nodemon -e js,jsx ./bin/www
$nodemon --ext 'js jsx' ./bin/www
```

I assume it can't see the root directory.

Comment: Same problem here bro. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Embarrassingly I rebooted and it started working..... Turned out I had a bad memory card. Not sure if the dozen changes I made fixed it, reboot or the replacement of a memory card.